# What does *test++ = count + '0'; do?

Tags: c++

Here is some sample code I am playing around with:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    char string[] = "hello";
    char *test = string;

    int count = 0;
    *test++ = count + '0';
    count++;
    *test++ = count + '0';

    std:: cout << test << std:: endl;

}
```

The output is **llo**.

I know this is probably very simple but I am confused about this line of code: `*test++ = count + '0';`. If `count = 0`, what does adding the `'0'` do (adding a zero)? And when evaluating `*test++`, the position of test is first incremented, and then dereferenced? What exactly is it being assigned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`char` stores numeric encodings of character, so `count + '0'` is simply the sum of two numbers. As a practical matter, the digits `0`, ..., `9` tend to have consecutive encodings, so a quick hack to convert a digit into the (encoding of the) corresponding character is `digit + '0'`.

`*p++` is parsed as `*(p++)` and is a common idiom for "get the thing that `p` points to, then advance `p`". So `*p++ = x` stores `x` in the place that `p` initially points to, and afterwards `p` points to the next place.

(recall that the value of `z++` is the value stored in `z` *before* it gets incremented, not the value it has *after* being incremented)

Answer (score 2):

Look at the table of ASCII characters. The characters '0' through '9' are consecutive. Adding '0' to `count` converts `count`, which could be a number 0 through 9, to character '0' through '9'.

As far as `*test++` goes, it's the other way around, `test` is first dereferenced, then it gets incremented.

To summarize, `count`, a number between 0 through 9, to character '0' through '9', assigns it to `*test`, then increments `test`.